# How to convert MP3 to PCM using delphi code?

Tags: delphi, mp3, wav, pcm

I have Bass component from http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html. I load mp3 and triying to change the format to PCM but it wont do nothing?

or any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You might have better luck asking about using some library, on the support forum for that library. Chance that anybody else here uses this library? Close to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is asked in http://www.un4seen.com/forum/?topic=11403.0 by XBasic3000 and answered

Comment: Just referring to the other thread so others with same question will be redirected to that thread.